# Electron + Nuxt: Getting warning with Bootstrap-vue ( $attrs is readonly, $listeners is readonly )

Tags: electron, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I am getting following warnings when using Bootstrap-vue in Electron + Nuxt.

[image]

I can't understand what it is.

I created my project using https://github.com/michalzaq12/electron-nuxt/tree/master/template , and versions are as following:

Electron : 8.3.0

Nuxt.js : 2.14.7

Bootstrap-vue : 2.19.0

I already searched many articles and tried with several methods, but couldn't resolve this issue.

Please help me.

PS: part of login.vue

```
<form
@submit.prevent="formSubmit"
class="av-tooltip tooltip-label-bottom"
>
    <b-form-group label="E-mail" class="has-float-label mb-4">
      <b-form-input
        type="text"
        v-model="email"
        placeholder="Please enter your email address"
      />
    </b-form-group>

    <b-form-group label="Password" class="has-float-label mb-4">
      <b-form-input
        type="password"
        v-model="password"
        placeholder="Please enter your password"
      />
    </b-form-group>
</form>
```

Comment: cannot find `colxx.vue` or `login.vue` could you provide us this too?

Comment: @Ifaruki, I edited my post. I think it's enough. I used b-form-group and b-form-input. and they are reason of this issue.